flutter al realizar un fullstar no se ven las img que fueron asociadas en sqllite?
Quiero consultar cuando se realiza un full start en visual studio Code las img locales que fueron guardadas las rutas en sql lite ya no existe esto en un entorno de iOS y quiero saber si hay una solución para este problema
Future<String> guardarRutaImg(File imagen) async {
  try {
    // Leer el archivo de imagen como bytes
    final Uint8List bytes = await imagen.readAsBytes();
    
    // Guardar la imagen en la galería
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));

    if (result['isSuccess']) {
      print('Imagen guardada en la galería correctamente');
      print(imagen.path);
      return imagen.path; 
    } else {
      print('Error al guardar la imagen en la galería');
      return '';
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Manejo de errores
    print('Error al guardar la imagen en la galería: $e');
    return '';
  }
}


